# How to run multiple keras programs on single gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a python project where i need to build multiple Keras models for each dataset. Here when i run a Keras model building the program is using 10% of my GPU(GTX 1050ti).

My question is there way i can use my gpu 100% to reduce the time? or is there a possibility to run multiple programs on same gpu?

I have tried to run multiple programs on single gpu but it is not running parallel, as an example when i run single python program it took 5 sec for each epoch whereas if i run 2 programs for each epoch the time duration is increased to 10 sec, what is the best approach to run multiple programs.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if there is a proper way of doing this, but this "gambiarra" may work quite well, it seems.

Make a model joining two or more models together in parallel. The only drawback is: you need the same number of input samples when training and predicting them in parallel.

How to use two models in parallel with a functional API model:

```
input1 = Input(inputShapeOfModel1)
input2 = Input(inputShapeOfModel2)

output1 = model1(input1)
output2 = model2(input2) #it could be model1 again, using model1 twice in parallel. 

parallelModel = Model([input1,input2], [output1,output2])
```

You train and predict with this model, passing parallel input and output data:

```
parallelModel.fit([x_train1, x_train2], [y_train1, y_train2], ...)
```

---

#### Working test code:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import numpy as np

#simulating two "existing" models
model1 = Sequential()
model2 = Sequential()

#creating "existing" model 1
model1.add(Conv2D(10,3,activation='tanh', input_shape=(20,20,3)))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

#creating "existing" model 2
model2.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(2,)))
model2.add(Dense(3))


#part containing the proposed answer: joining the two models in parallel
inp1 = Input((20,20,3))
inp2 = Input((2,))

out1 = model1(inp1)
out2 = model2(inp2)

model = Model([inp1,inp2],[out1,out2])


#treat the new model as any other model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

#dummy input data x and y, for models 1 and 2
x1 = np.ones((30,20,20,3))
y1 = np.ones((30,1))
x2 = np.ones((30,2))
y2 = np.ones((30,3))

#training the model and predicting
model.fit([x1,x2],[y1,y2], epochs = 50)
ypred1,ypred2 = model.predict([x1,x2])

print(ypred1.shape)
print(ypred2.shape)
```

---

#### Advanced solution - Grouping data for speed and matching the amount of samples

There is still space for more optimizing, since this approach will synchronize batches between two models. So, if a model is much faster than another, the fast model will adjust to the speed of the slow model.

Also, if you have a different number of batches, you will need to train/predict some remaining data in separate.

You can work around these limitations too if you group your input data and use some custom reshapes in the model with a Lambda layer where you reshape the batch dimension at the beginning and then restore it at the end.

For instance, if `x1` has 300 samples and `x2` has 600 samples, you can reshape the input and output:

```
x2 = x2.reshape((300,2,....))
y2 = y2.reshape((300,2,....))
```

Before and after `model2`, you use:

```
#before
Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,....))) #transforms in the inner's model input shape

#after
Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1,2,....))) #transforms in the grouped shape for output
```

Where `....` is the original input and output shapes (not considering batch_size).

Then you need to ponder which is best, group data to synchronize data size or group data to synchronize speed.

(Advantage compared to the next solution: you can easily group by any number, such as 2, 5, 10, 200.....)

#### Advanced solution - Using the same model more than once in parallel to double speed

You can also use the same model twice in parallel, such as in this code. This will probably double its speed.

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
#import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
#import tensorflow as tf


#simulating two "existing" models
model1 = Sequential()
model2 = Sequential()

#model 1
model1.add(Conv2D(10,3,activation='tanh', input_shape=(20,20,3)))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

#model 2
model2.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(2,)))
model2.add(Dense(3))

#joining the models
inp1 = Input((20,20,3))

#two inputs for model 2 (the model we want to run twice as fast)
inp2 = Input((2,))
inp3 = Input((2,))

out1 = model1(inp1)
out2 = model2(inp2) #use model 2 once
out3 = model2(inp3) #use model 2 twice

model = Model([inp1,inp2,inp3],[out1,out2,out3])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

#dummy data - remember to have two inputs for model 2, not repeated
x1 = np.ones((30,20,20,3))
y1 = np.ones((30,1))
x2 = np.ones((30,2)) #first input for model 2
y2 = np.ones((30,3)) #first output for model 2
x3 = np.zeros((30,2)) #second input for model 2
y3 = np.zeros((30,3)) #second output for model 2

model.fit([x1,x2,x3],[y1,y2,y3], epochs = 50)
ypred1,ypred2,ypred3 = model.predict([x1,x2,x3])

print(ypred1.shape)
print(ypred2.shape)
print(ypred3.shape)
```

Advantage compared to the previous solution: less trouble with manipulating data and custom reshapes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am not great in functional API but i will try the solution which you have given. Just to give an overview of my task, i am using the sequential model using LSTM architecture to predict time series. It is pretty simple code. However the problem is i need to run the same program for each dataset to build model and where i need to predict data of each dataset.

Comment: You can use the same model more than once in parallel, as in the last part of my answer. Then you divide your data in two parts.

Comment: I really suggest people to learn the funcitonal API, it's not hard and it creates a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Is there a way of specifying that each 'inner model' is trained on a specific GPU (given that there are at least 2 GPUs available) ?

Comment: Uses `with tf.device` in each segment of model definition: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device - I think this is better with functional API, not with Sequential.

Comment: Using this approach, how can I pass individual callbacks to each model?

Comment: Not possible, I think.

Comment: I've tried your last advanced solution on my code by comparing (A) a model contains several identical submodels, and (B) just a single submodel. I find that loss of each submodel in (A) goes down MUCH SLOWLIER than (B). They should go down at same speed since (A) is trained on sum of losses of all submodels, and each submodel updates on its own loss. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @NgJuPing, there may be many things going on. You may be reaching the GPU limit, and  thus limiting the speed for the big model. You may have a learning rate problem, since you're summing losses for the same model, the resulting learning rate for this model is probably multiplied by the number of repetitions.